# Writing new users to JSON file using post Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to append new objects of users to a json file with spring boot.
The data is sens through a post from an angular form to my spring boot backend, on every new registration a user needs to be added to the json file.

I'm trying to use an outputstream to write to a json file that sits in my resources folder but it doesnt seem to work because the fileoutputstream cant find the file.

my code:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/api/register", consumes = "application/json")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        User newUser = new User(user.getfirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Paths.get("src/main/resources/data/users.json"));
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

        // write the user to the file
        writer.write(newUser);
        writer.flush();

        return "user is added";
    }
```

- is this the right way to write an append new users to the file straight away (the users who are already in the file can't be overwritten)? or is it better to add them to an arraylist and then write the array list to the file?

Comment: Why you don't use a database? It's easier and prettier way. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is better to use a database instead of writing to a file

but if you want to write in file in resource , try this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(classLoader.getResource("data/users.json").getFile()));
```

also if first add user in array list then write to file , This causes the data to be stored in RAM, and if the server is down at some point (before write array list on file), the data will be lost

Comment: Thanks this works, I will use a database eventually. But for now I want to store it in a JSON file until I know how to use and save it in an MySQL database.